# Regarding longest path between nodes in directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Recently I formulated the following problem while solving a question. It has been bugging me since. It is as follows:

Given a directed acyclic graph $G$ with $n$ edges, define $l(x,y)$ = longest distance between vertex $x$ and $y$ in $G$. Let $D$ be a set defined as follows: $D = \{ (x,y) | l(x,y) \le \sqrt n \}$.

The question is: Can we give any bound on |$D$|?
Can we generalize this bound when the number of edges is $m$ and $l(x,y) \le \sqrt m$.

I am not sure if there is a closed expression for $|D|$. Any pointer to related material(if any) will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What if there is no longest path?  For example, suppose there is a directed cycle containing $x$.  Then you can find arbitrarily long paths from $x$ to $y$; for any path there is another path that is longer.

Comment: Presumably all edges that are part of a cycle would not be among the pairs of $D$, if the poster is using the convention $\infty > \sqrt{n}$.  (As well as the pairs that could pass through a cycle)

Comment: Based on MJD comment, the upper bound probably occurs in a very dense DAG (highest edge to vertex ratio).

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Assume that the graph is a DAG.